# Calendar.roll weird result when using Calendar.DATE

Tags: java, datetime, calendar

Today, in Europe, the date is 1 October 2015. Can you tell me why running this code displays the date as 31 Oct 2015?

```
Calendar yesterday = Calendar.getInstance();
yesterday.roll(Calendar.DATE, false);
System.out.println(yesterday.getTime());
```

Comment: What does the javadoc say? What do you think it should display? Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Calendar.DATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DATE) represents the day of the month, not the day of the year. Thus, when rolling the day of the month backwards of 1 unit, we are essentially going from the 1st to the last day of the month.

Quoting the [`roll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#roll-int-boolean-) Javadoc (emphasis mine):

> Adds or subtracts (up/down) a single unit of time on the given time field **without changing larger fields**.

and quoting the [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) Javadoc:

> A larger field represents a larger unit of time.

As such, fields like MONTH or YEAR are not changed by this method when rolling the day of the month.

You should use [`Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#DAY_OF_YEAR) instead:

```
Calendar yesterday = Calendar.getInstance();
yesterday.roll(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, false);
System.out.println(yesterday.getTime());
```

Comment: Using DAY_OF_YEAR I would have the same issue on the 1 day of january, right? Better find another way to retrieve the day before the current day...